# Comb Sort Implementation Doesn't Accurately Sort, C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I attempted to implement the pseudocode for comb sort on wikipedia but it doest appear to sort the sample array I give it. Any tips?

```
void combSort(int* list, int length)
{
bool swapper;
int gap = length;
double shrink = 1.25;
int temp;
do{
    gap = (int) gap/shrink;
    if (gap < 1)
        gap = 1;

    swapper = false;
    for (int i=0;(i+gap)<length;i++){
        if (list[i] > list[i+gap]){
            swap(list[i],list[i+gap]);
            swapper = true;
        }
    }
}
while ((gap > 1) && (swapper == true));
}
```

Comment: If you're going with C++, why not use the Standard Library containers like `std::array` or `std::vector` here? What you have here is essentially C code.

Comment: And if it is C, the swap function probably doesn't work.  You need to pass by reference, not value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to wikipedia document you should change the last predicate.
The valid solution:

```
void combSort(int* list, int length)
{
    bool swapper;
    int gap = length;
    double shrink = 1.25;
    int temp;
    do {
        gap = (int)gap / shrink;
        if (gap < 1)
            gap = 1;

        swapper = false;
        for (int i = 0; (i + gap)<length; i++) {
            if (list[i] > list[i + gap]) {
                swap(list[i], list[i + gap]);
                swapper = true;
            }
        }
    } while ((gap > 1) || (swapper == true));
}
```

Changed line: **while ((gap > 1) || (swapper == true));**

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the wiki, it wasn't immediately apparent to me that having both conditions be false as a requirement of leaving the loop would need the "or" instead of "and".